# How to add fullcalendar.print.css to my page

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm struggling to implement the print.css that's included with fullcalendar.  I've seen references to an instruction sheet, but can't find that either.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just include it for use when printing

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fullcalendar.print.css" media="print" />
```

Comment: I was making it way to complicated.  Thanks.